# java load data infile query discarding wrong lines

Tags: java, mysql, load-data-infile

Java application insert data to mysql using **load data infile** query. In csv file, some wrong formatted values like lacking rows, improper fields (string value for integer value). If there is non-correct record(line) on file, java application throws exception and do not add **any** records even correct lines. If execute same query for same file using heidi sql program (sql client program), add all records, even non-correct lines (put null value for lacking fields etc). I just want to my java application behave like sql client, put all lines at least insert correctly well-formed lines.

Thanks.

sql

```
load data infile '/a.txt'  into table test_data fields terminated by ','
```

code snippet

```
public void query(String query, Connection conn) throws SQLException {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (MySQLTransactionRollbackException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            throw new MySQLTransactionRollbackException();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            throw new SQLException(e);
        } finally {

            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("", e);
                }
            }

            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("", e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ignore** keyword is solution.

```
load data infile '/a.txt'  **ignore** into table test_data fields terminated by ','
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot discard wrong lines as they might causing parsing failure of the entire file.With very good algorithms it can be done, but i dont think there will be 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

ignore is correct, but supposing you need to know the details of the dropped records..

A long and tedious solution is to dump a file after the load and compare the PK values with an extract from your infile using diff say.

This will not distinguish key violations from referential integrity violations though.